# What is the equivalent of left and right quotation marks in python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, web, symbols

I'm trying to parse the web for certain strings and when I'm parsing this one string that includes the left and right quotation marks, I get an error for '\u201c...\u201d'. I'm trying to ignore this string with an if something != '(left quotation mark symbol)' ignore it. What's the equivalent for it?

Comment: What do you mean, the equivalent? That Unicode code point is the character. Your console simply doesn't want to render it. Why not just replace it with an acceptable character, like `"`, before printing the string?

Comment: Well I'm trying to parse a website that has that character included. The console can't render it so I'm trying to find a way for it to identify it, so it can ignore it instead of giving me a u'\u201cLonny\u201d'

Comment: Like I said, why not just `replace()` those characters before you try to print them?

Comment: I can't replace them because I have no idea how to tell my console to replace that symbol. I'm actually trying to ignore it and not print it out so instead of hardcoding a removal since the list I'm parsing is long, I'm trying to create a set of commands and ignores any left and right quotation mark symbols.

Comment: Do you want to ignore just those symbols, or the whole string containing those symbols?

Comment: Either of the two, right now I have a command where if the character is equal to the double quotation marks, ignore the whole string. I'm just having trouble with telling python what those particular quotation marks are.

Comment: They are `'\u201c'` and `'\u201d'`. Use them like any other character: `if '\u201c in line:...`.

Comment: Or you could do `print(line.replace('\u201c', '"').replace('\u201d', '"'))` to have the printout use ordinary `"` instead of smart quotes.